# How to close a IWpfTextView based on a condition from the IWpfTextViewCreationListener - VsTextViewCreated

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I have a class which listens to the IWpfTextViewCreationListener

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop;

namespace GoToSequence
{
    [Export(typeof(IVsTextViewCreationListener))]
    [ContentType("Code")]
    [TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable)]
    internal class GoToSequenceEditorCreationListener : IVsTextViewCreationListener
    {
        [Import(typeof(IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService))]
        internal IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService editorFactory = null;

        public void VsTextViewCreated(IVsTextView textViewAdapter)
        {
            IWpfTextView textView = editorFactory.GetWpfTextView(textViewAdapter);
            if (textView == null)
                return;

            AddCommandFilter(textViewAdapter, new GoToSequenceCommandHandler(textView, textViewAdapter));
        }

        void AddCommandFilter(IVsTextView viewAdapter, GoToSequenceCommandHandler commandFilter)
        {
            if (commandFilter.m_added == false)
            {
                //get the view adapter from the editor factory
                IOleCommandTarget next;
                int hr = viewAdapter.AddCommandFilter(commandFilter, out next);

                if (hr == VSConstants.S_OK)
                {
                    commandFilter.m_added = true;
                    //you'll need the next target for Exec and QueryStatus 
                    if (next != null)
                        commandFilter.m_nextTarget = next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the function - VsTextViewCreated, based on a certain condition I want to close the textview.

```
If (condition == null)
   IWpfTextView.Close()
```

However after doing this I get the following error

> System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled Message: An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll Additional information:
>   Cannot access a disposed object.

I also tried

```
if(condition == null)
  IVsTextView.CloseView()
```

but this also did not help. What could be the correct way to close the textview programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... I was able to resolve the above...

```
var dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE));
Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider sp = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)dte2;
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider(sp);

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIHierarchy uiHierarchy;
uint itemID;
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowFrame windowFrame;
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsShellUtilities.IsDocumentOpen(serviceProvider, _iTextDocument.FilePath, Guid.Empty, out uiHierarchy, out itemID, out windowFrame);

windowFrame.CloseFrame((uint)__FRAMECLOSE.FRAMECLOSE_NoSave);
```

But, I still wonder why doesn't the IWpfTextView.Close() or IVSTextView.CloseView() do not work...